# how to upload ziped file on server via ftp

Tags: python, ftp, upload

i have this code in python for upload photos.zip file on the server via ftp.

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
file = open('c:\archived\photos.zip','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR photos.zip', file)                 # send the file
file.close()                                                # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

but i have this error :
T

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 24, in <module>
file = open('c:\archived\photos.zip','rb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'c:\archived\photos.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the backslashes in the path:

```
file = open('c:\\archived\\photos.zip','rb')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join` which is considered better.

```
file = open(os.path.join('c:/','archived','photos.zip'),'rb')
```

If you want to stick to your string, use `\\` instead of `\`.